# Need Info on simulated turtlebot2(melodic and/or kinetic)

Tags: simulation, ros-melodic, turtlebot2, turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for where to get a simulated turtlebot2. I recall finding a github link but I cant remember. If anyone uses simulated turtlebot2s please tell me how you got it or if you can make a github link where I can get it please, its urgent. For ROS melodic and/or Kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391452/need-info-on-simulated-turtlebot2(melodic-and/or-kinetic)/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2021-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This [site](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations) could be your first step. There is this [book](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/hardware-and-creative/9781788479592/3/ch03lvl1sec24/launching-turtlebot-2-simulator-in-gazebo) where you could find more overall info too.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2021-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2021-12-21**:
@ljaniec  have you ever used a simulated turtlebot2?, Im trying to gmap with it now but its not working. I want to create a map

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-01-05**:
Does [this setup](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/slam/#run-slam-node) not work for you in your case?

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-01-08**:
@ljaniec some of the steps used in the textbook dont work.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-01-08**:
Which one? Please describe these steps and we will try to resolve them :^)

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-01-27**:
@Ijaniec  forget what I asked about ros melodic, I have started using a real turtlebot2, I have been following the instructions from the book you suggested, all was going well until I ran this command on my remote PC
`roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch`

I get this error:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
[rviz-1] process has died [pid 8017, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rviz/rviz -d /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_rviz_launchers/rviz/navigation.rviz __name:=rviz __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/39de43b2-7fed-11ec-a022-a0510b03a27d/rviz-1.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/39de43b2-7fed-11ec-a022-a0510b03a27d/rviz-1*.log
```

I dont know why, I can eleop my robot from my remote pc, and this same command that gives me an error on remote PC works just fine when I run it on the laptop connected to the turtlebot2 itself. DO you know whats going on?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-01-28**:
I have found some similar issues, I am not sure if they can help you though: [link1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367333/qxcbconnection-error), [link2](https://answers.ros.org/question/384743/rviz-qxcbconnection-xcb-error-148-unknown/), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811424/how-to-deal-with-qxcbconnection-error-message-when-running-a-python-script-in). It seems like the QXcvConnection couldn't connect to your monitor through your connection, did you use `-X` option with `ssh`?

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-01-29**:
@ljaniec I think my problem was that I didnt have the [turtlebot package](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot) in my remote PC. I'll install it and see what happens. Also, what planner does turtlebot2 use? DO I just install the ROS navigation stack to use that? I ask because I which to use DWA_local_planner for my tirtlebot2 and I need to change it's parameters to fit my use. When I'm using a turtlebot3 I can `roscd turtlebot3_navigation` and find the `.yaml` files that hold the parameters I wish to change. Is there a `roscd turtlebot2_navigation` type thing?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-01-29**:
There is [a tutorial for a navigation stack setup on the TurtleBot](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Setup%20the%20Navigation%20Stack%20for%20TurtleBot) and [an example exercises](https://sceweb.sce.uhcl.edu/harman/CENG5435_ROS/CENG5435_D158Exercises/Ch4_Lab_TurtleBotGazebo_10_24_18/TurtleBot_Navigation_Exercise10_24_2018.pdf). [The general navigation package](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation#Navigation_Tutorials_for_the_TurtleBot) has a few tutorials too. I hope it could help you.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-01-29**:
@ljaniec the [turtlebot navigation package](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps) seems to not be created for ros kinetic? I see ros indigo, no kinetic, I'm using kinetic, what do I do?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-01-29**:
It's weird, ROS Wiki shows me [kinetic version](https://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation?distro=kinetic), same with ROS Index [there](https://index.ros.org/p/turtlebot_navigation/github-turtlebot-turtlebot_apps/#kinetic). You can try to use the older version anyway to see if you have any problems during building/using it (which maybe you can fix to update the package for your case)

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-01-29**:
@ljaniec when you actually click on the repo link that the wiki page offers, you'll see that only indigo is available, there are others, but no ros kinetic branch

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-02-02**:
@ljaniec Thank you. I was able to get what I needed to work. Now I have a follow up question about turtlebot2  [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/395503/inquiry-on-how-to-use-movebaseactiongoal-with-turtlebot2/) if you have the time.